# How to copy attributes from a SVG to another?

Tags: python, xml, svg

I have two SVGs that where the same but I changed some values inside, for instance:

**SVG1**

```
<desc
   id="desc20622">[Visualization]
       name=H131B1;
</desc>
```

and the other is:

**SVG2**

```
<desc
   id="desc20622">[Visualization]
       name=R131C2;
</desc>
```

Now I have realocated a lot of elements in one SVG and I would like to replicate this changes to the other SVG. How is the simplest way to consume those SVGs, compare the ids, copy the values from SVG2 to SVG1 and save a new SVG file?
I'm familiar with a bunch of programming languages but I was taking a look at Python to do this job using `minidom` or `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Could some one help me on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the two SVGs were the same at the beginning and you made changes to one of them, isn't just copying it enough?

Comment: The SVG has almost 50k lines and I took a lot of time to change the values and don't want to wast more time on it, and also want to have something ready if I have to change the disposal of elements again!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you completely: SVGs are just text files, you can use version control system (e.g. git). Then you will have all history you made to the SVG at hand.

Comment: I know! I do have it versioned but the point is that I had that huge SVG, replicated it to another one and changed the value as written before. Now I've changed the drawing position of a lot of them and want that the replicated svg had the same position so I have 2 choices: 1-change a position of each element ex. `transform="translate(1040.8435.346.27772)"` to `transform="translate(-10,-9.31067)"` or 2-copy and change the value ex. change H131B1 to R131C2

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it by my own with Python.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree1 = ET.parse('SVG1.svg')
root1 = tree1.getroot()

tree2 = ET.parse('SVG2.svg')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

for child1 in root1.iter('desc'):
    for child2 in root2.iter('desc'):
        if child1.attrib == child2.attrib:
            child1.text = child2.text
            break

tree1.write('output.svg')
```

Just have to parse both SVGs, iterate on every `desc` compare the id and copy the text!